# IsEmpty excel vba

Tags: excel, vba

Hi I am trying to skip a sub if the usedrange is empty, the coding is below:

```
Dim myRange As Range
Dim yrow As long 
yrow = Tests_Finish.UsedRange.Rows.Count 

Set myRange = Tests_Finish.Range(“A1:Z” & yrow)

If IsEmpty(“myRange”) = True Then exit Sub

Tests_Finished.Range(“L2:L” & yrow).Value = “Vlookup(RC[-6],FinishedPivot!C1:C6,2,False)”

End if
```

Can someone help to not run the vlookup if the sheet usedrange is empty?

Comment: You don't want the quotations around `myRange` if you want to reference a variable:  `IsEmpty(myRange) = True`

Comment: You also cannot do `IsEmpty` on a range of cells.

Comment: How about instead you do: `If yrow<2 Then exit Sub`

Comment: @Cyril thank you, I didn’t know that I couldn’t use that function on a range

Comment: *What if in VB you compare an uninitialized variant to an uninitialized integer? It seems sensible that the comparison would return True, and it does. Empty compares as equal to 0 and the empty string, which might cause false positives in our example above. If you need to detect whether a variable actually is an empty variant and not a string or a number, you can use IsEmpty. (Alternatively, you could use TypeName or VarType, but I prefer IsEmpty.)*. https://ericlippert.com/2003/09/30/a-whole-lot-of-nothing/

Comment: So you never need in general code `IsEmpty`, `Is Nothing`, or `null`. These are for very specific purposes, not general code. You need to look at the sample code in the documentation on how you are supposed to code. Take a string that may or may not have contents, one does `If strA = "" then`.